# How to deal with change from summer to winter time when using resampling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, forecasting

I have a dataframe that I would like to use for a load forecast. The data is recordes every 15 minutes. I would first like to resample the data by calculating the mean for every hour. For this purpose I use the resampling function from pandas
`new_df = df['Load'].resample('1H').mean()`

Bascially this is not a problem as long as the time data is consistant regarding winter and summer time. However, when having a switch this get problematic (and I get an Type Error). So here you see an extract of the data that shows the change from summer to winter time
[image]

and here you see the data when changing from winter time to summer time:

[image]

In the first case some hour values (02:00, 02:15, 02:30, 02:45) exist 2 time this is why I get an error when trying to resampe it. In the latter case the values for these specific hours are missing. Now my question is how to deal with that problem? Is there a way to tell pandas that the one is summer time and the other one is winter time? In the data itself this is indicated with the addition "+02:00" or "+01:00" but this is still a problem for pandas. Or can you think about any other solution? One naive approach would be just to delete the 4 data records when changing from summer to winter time (first case) and to copy the previous 4 data record when changing from winter to summer time.

**Reminder**: Does nobody have an idea or a suggestion? This problem should occur also for others.

Comment: Why not harmonize all the timestamps to UTC+0, then resample?

Comment: @timgeb: Thanks timgeb for your answer. How can I do that in padas/python or would you do this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an `Index` of timestamps (or maybe strings), but not a `DatetimeIndex`, because a `DatetimeIndex` cannot hold timestamps with heterogenous timezone information.

This is unwieldy, so my suggestion is to create a proper `DatetimeIndex` first, and then do whatever resampling you need to do afterwards.

Here's a small DataFrame with mixed timezone timestamps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [1, 2],
    index=pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('12:00:00+01:00'), pd.Timestamp('12:00:00+00:00')])
)
```

It does not have a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
>>> df
                           0
2021-05-31 12:00:00+01:00  1
2021-05-31 12:00:00+00:00  2
>>> type(df.index)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
```

In order to construct a `DatetimeIndex` for `df`, we need to decide on a common timezone, so let's use UTC+0.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True)
```

The DataFrame now looks like this and has a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
>>> df
                           0
2021-05-31 11:00:00+00:00  1
2021-05-31 12:00:00+00:00  2
>>> type(df.index)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

Notice how `2021-05-31 12:00:00+01:00` became `2021-05-31 11:00:00+00:00`.

Comment: Thanks timgeb for your answer. I tried your suggested code but I get an error telling "ParserError: Unknown string format: 2018-04-21 00:00:00+02:00 4470". I used the following code for that `dataset_original = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Generation.csv', sep=';', header=0, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1]}, index_col=['datetime'])
dataset_original.index = pd.to_datetime(dataset_original.index, utc=True)`

Comment: I also tried the following code `dataset_original = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Generation.csv', sep=';', header=0, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True) dataset_original.index = pd.to_datetime(dataset_original.index, utc=True)` so reading the csv file without the arguments " parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1]}, index_col=['datetime']". Now I do not get an error. However, the timestemps of the dataframe are quite weird. They begin in 1970 and have entries like "1970-01-01 00:00:00.00000000001+00:00" and "1970-01-01 00:00:00.00000000002+00:00" etc.. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: @PeterBe what is 4470 at the end of the date string?

Comment: Thanks for your comment timgeb. Basically I found my mistake. I used `parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1]}` instead of `parse_dates={'datetime':[0]}`. In the frist version I think pandas also tries to use the second column as a datetime index which was not correct.

Comment: Now basically your suggested code works. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer.